# Android Studio Kotlin DatePicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

How can I round the corners of a DatePicker without creating a custom DatePicker from scratch? Can I somehow assign a background shape to xml?

I tried to add styles in themes where I registered android:background corners_20dp.xml But it didn't work out that way.

I really need help. Thank you in advance for the ideas and ways of implementation!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for this problem. I'm explain how can you do step by step.

First, create new `Drawable Resource File`, you can do this with right click in your drawable folder after that you can give name `rounded_corner` click `OK` file will be created.

Write this in your drawable xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="28dp" />
    <solid android:color="?colorBackgroundFloating" />
</shape>
```

Now, we can give this rounded corner for DatePicker, for this we use that code:

```
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
    requireContext(),
    { _, y, m, d ->
        // it's listener
    },
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
)

// Here is giving rounded corner for DatePicker
datePicker.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        requireContext(),
        R.drawable.rounded_corner
    )
)

datePicker.show()
```

Result:
[image: Result for DatePicker with rounded corner]

Comment: Wow, thank you, kind man :) Very accessible answer, solved my problem. You're cool!